# How to add libraries to "External Libraries" in WebStorm/PhpStorm/Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to add libraries to "External Libraries".  I've added them in `Setting -> Javascript -> Libraries` and they are highlighted now as "(library home)", but they are not added to external libraries which allows code inspection and TODO's to work for them.

What is the difference between "library home" and "External Libraries" and how do I make a library external?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't really know how it works in WebStorm, but in PhpStorm the stuff listed under External Libraries would be: 1) PHAR files; 2) folders from `Settings | PHP | Include paths` (folders that are not part of the actual project but still referenced for code completion: e.g. libraries installed globally). Quite likely it's the same here: global npm modules or whatever. So *I guess* when you reference a library that is physically located outside of the project, it should be listed there.

Comment: Thanks, LazyOne. You seems to be right about `when you reference a library that is physically located outside of the project, it should be listed there`. I added such library to libraries and it is indeed is listed under `External Libraries`. You can make it as an answer here so I can accept it.

Comment: So the question now is why `TODO`s are shown for libraries that are not external (located within a project). Do you know if it's the expected behavior? I'd assume that once I mark files as library no inspection should take place there regardless of the location (within the project or external)

Comment: AFAIK -- Yes, it's expected (for "local" libraries). But that's very easy to bypass in TODO window.

Comment: Thanks. `But that's very easy to bypass in TODO window` - are you referring to using Scope Based view and creating own scope which excludes lib libraries?

Comment: Correct -- using it myself. My only hope would be to have JB implementing separate scope for that themselves which will include only "normal" code and will exclude excluded/generated/libraries content automatically.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In PhpStorm the stuff listed under External Libraries branch will include:

- PHAR files
- folders from `Settings | PHP | Include paths` (folders that are not part of the actual project but still referenced for code completion: e.g. libraries installed globally).

Quite likely it's the same here in WebStorm for JavaScript libraries: **global** npm modules or whatever. So *I guess* when you reference a library that is **physically located outside of the project**, it should be listed there.

Comment: Hi. I download phpseclib from github , extract phpseclib and add on my external libraries with your method. But I can't reach phpseclib functions, I can't use them. I tries use and include_once but I couldn't make it